# What does QHeaderView::paintSection do such that all I do to the painter before or after is ignored

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qheaderview

This question is further development of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170922/how-can-i-get-the-background-color-returned-by-model-take-precedence-over-the-st?noredirect=1#comment48496527_30170922) and is different, though may seem similar as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489640/implement-paintsection-for-qheaderview-delivered-class).

I am trying to reimplement `QHeaderView::paintSection`, so that the background returned from the model would be honored. I tried to do this

```
void Header::paintSection(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int logicalIndex) const
{
    QVariant bg = model()->headerData(logicalIndex, Qt::Horizontal, Qt::BackgroundRole);
    // try before
    if(bg.isValid())                // workaround for Qt bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46216
        painter->fillRect(rect, bg.value<QBrush>());             
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
    // try after
    if(bg.isValid())                // workaround for Qt bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46216
        painter->fillRect(rect, bg.value<QBrush>());             
}
```

However, it didn't work - if I make `QHeaderView::paintSection` call, nothing I draw with the painter is visible (I also tried drawing a diagonal line). If I remove `QHeaderView::paintSection` call, the line and the background will be visible.
Making the `fillRect` call before vs. after the `QHeaderView::paintSection` doesn't make any difference.

I wonder, what is it that `QHeaderView::paintSection` does that makes it impossible for me to draw something on top of it.
And whether there is a way to overcome it without reimplementing everythning what `QHeaderView::paintSection` does?

All I need to do is to add a certain shade to a certain cell - I still want everything in the cell (text, icons, gradient background etc.) to be painted as it is now...

Comment: What would `bg.value<QBrush>()` return ? is it a valid `QBrush` ?

Comment: The model would either return a QBrush or an empty QVariant (if no custom background is needed). bg.isValid takes care of the later. So, yes - bg.value<QBrush>() returns the valid brush. And if I comment the QHeaderView::paintSection call, I can see the rect being correctly filled

Comment: The `QHeaderView::paintSection` is drawing on top of your rectangle... it may be covering it ... try changing the order of the calls

Comment: I tried both before and after, same result - nothing shows up

Comment: I tried both before and after - updated code sample - neither works

Comment: Can you post a picture of how you want it to look like and what are you getting instead in both cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is obvious why the first `fillRect` doesn't work. Everything that you paint before `paintSection` is overridden by base painting.

The second call is more interesting.

Usually all paint methods preserves `painter` state. It means that when you call `paint` it looks like the painter state hasn't been changed.

Nevertheless `QHeaderView::paintSection` spoils the painter state.

To bypass the issue you need to save and restore the state by yourself:

```
void Header::paintSection(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int logicalIndex) const
{
    QVariant bg = model()->headerData(logicalIndex, Qt::Horizontal, Qt::BackgroundRole);
    painter->save();
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
    painter->restore();
    if(bg.isValid())               
        painter->fillRect(rect, bg.value<QBrush>());             
}
```

Comment: How can I implement this.  Do I need a .h and .cpp for the above?  What code do I need in main() to color my headers?