# QT TableWidget header change given column background color

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have QT TableWidget and I would like to change background color of column based on their value. Seems I can change all columns background doing something like this:

`tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section {background-color: red}");`

But I want to change color for given column and each column color can be different. Anyone has done anything like this ?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847252/what-does-qheaderviewpaintsection-do-such-that-all-i-do-to-the-painter-before

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using QTableView and the Qt Model/View framework to do that.